# Need to index a huge postgres table text column that works for wild card search both at the beginning and the end '%xyz%'

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a Postgres 9.6 database running in production. It has a table that has around 98,000,000 rows and is growing.

It has a column `file_path` that stores the relative path to a file. Example: `/directory1/123456/CT1_1111_111_111-CT2_2222_222_222-fail.xml`. The values of the `CTx_xxx` keep changing.

Currently there are no indexes on this column since we didn't really do a search using it. However, the need has arisen to fetch using this column with no other supporting indexed columns. What makes my problem harder is that the search needs to support wild card search, where file_path like `'%CT1_1111%'`.

Running this in a query takes forever as expected. I need to index this column, but can't seem to find a solution for this.

A simple b-tree index obviously didn't work since it wont support `LIKE`.
Then I tried the `text_pattern_ops` too. That won't work either due to the preceding wild card.

I tried the `gin_trgm_ops` index too, but that search was super slow as well. This table has a cardinality of 1.14793103E10

I expect to have a query to be able to return the result in - say - 2-3 secs. My problem is that this is a very old database structure with a lot of rows. I would want to avoid restructuring the db for the same reason.

Comment: First of all, we'd need you to provide an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...` from your currently fastest query (best after a `SET track_io_timing TO ON` - if not already enabled) as a reference from where to start.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `CREATE INDEX` for the trigram index and the exact query you used (plus the output fo `explain (analyze, buffers)` as suggested by Ancoron in plain text (no screen shots please).

Comment: If you have a certain pattern at the `file_path` and you are always going to search for a specific part in the path (in this case indicates parts of the filename), you can also create one or more b-tree indexes using string functions and then query it (potentially using an `OR`) using the exact same functions and `=`. That's going to be fastest. With `gin_trgm_ops` you will also use way more disk space than with `btree`. See also the comments in https://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/ for details

Answer (score 2):

There will most likely be no guarantee for the 2-3 seconds response time. At least not as long as disk I/O is involved and you're not running on latest SSD (or even better: NVMe) with high IOPS and lowest latency. Also enough RAM is a requirement here. Please consider this before deciding about the indexing strategy.

If neither your data nor the indexes fit into memory, you have to be sure to reduce the number of disk I/O's per query as much as possible or let PostgreSQL use strategies that helps mitigating random I/O at least (e.g. what bitmap index scans where built for).

Text search using `LIKE` in a *contains substring* manner is not going to perform well on any big table.

An alternative (will only work if queries are searching for the same parts in `file_path`) could be (for your example searching for `CTX_XXXX`):

```sql
-- create a function to extract the specific file_path substring
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_filename_part(file_path text, idx int)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
AS $$
    SELECT regexp_replace(file_path, '.*/(CT.{6}).*-(CT.{6}).*', E'\\' || idx);
$$;

-- create a helper function for querying...
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_filename_parts(file_path text, c_value text)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
AS $$
    SELECT get_filename_part(file_path, 1) = c_value OR get_filename_part(file_path, 2) = c_value;
$$;

-- create indexes...
CREATE INDEX idx_filename_ct_first ON text_search (get_filename_part(file_path, 1));
CREATE INDEX idx_filename_ct_second ON text_search (get_filename_part(file_path, 2));
```

...and use a query such as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM text_search
WHERE check_filename_parts(file_path, 'CT1_1111');
```

**Explained with test data**

> Please note that the following tests where made using 8 years old consumer-grade hardware (but at least using an SSD).

Create test data (8,000,000 rows - pretty much random):

```sql
CREATE TABLE text_search (id serial PRIMARY KEY, file_path text);

INSERT INTO text_search (file_path)
SELECT '/directory1/123456/CT' || (random() * 8 + 1)::int || '_' || (random() * 8999 + 1000)::int || '_' || (random() * 899 + 100)::int || '_' || (random() * 899 + 100)::int || '-CT' || (random() * 8 + 1)::int || '_' || (random() * 8999 + 1000)::int || '_' || (random() * 899 + 100)::int || '_' || (random() * 899 + 100)::int || '-fail.xml'
FROM generate_series(1, 8000000);

--- and analyze...
ANALYZE text_search;
```

...explained above select query (after a server restart):

```sql
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on text_search  (cost=5.49..409.93 rows=203 width=66) (actual time=0.092..0.882 rows=110 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((get_filename_part(file_path, 1) = 'CT1_1111'::text) OR (get_filename_part(file_path, 2) = 'CT1_1111'::text))
   Heap Blocks: exact=110
   Buffers: shared read=116
   I/O Timings: read=0.576
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=5.49..5.49 rows=203 width=0) (actual time=0.071..0.072 rows=0 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared read=6
         I/O Timings: read=0.036
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_filename_ct_first  (cost=0.00..2.70 rows=102 width=0) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=48 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (get_filename_part(file_path, 1) = 'CT1_1111'::text)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               I/O Timings: read=0.017
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_filename_ct_second  (cost=0.00..2.69 rows=101 width=0) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=62 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (get_filename_part(file_path, 2) = 'CT1_1111'::text)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               I/O Timings: read=0.019
 Planning Time: 4.996 ms
 Execution Time: 0.922 ms
(18 rows)
```

**Generic filter using gin_trgm_ops**

...compared to a generic `LIKE` query using a `gin_trgm_ops` index (after 3 runs - data in cache):

```sql
-- create index...
CREATE INDEX idx_filename ON text_search USING gin (file_path gin_trgm_ops);

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT *
FROM text_search
WHERE file_path LIKE '%CT1_1111%';

                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on text_search  (cost=94.70..1264.40 rows=800 width=66) (actual time=20.699..27.775 rows=110 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (file_path ~~ '%CT1_1111%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 8207
   Heap Blocks: exact=7978
   Buffers: shared hit=8277
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_filename  (cost=0.00..94.50 rows=800 width=0) (actual time=19.328..19.328 rows=8317 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (file_path ~~ '%CT1_1111%'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=299
 Planning Time: 0.722 ms
 Execution Time: 27.912 ms
(10 rows)
```

**TL;DR**

If possible by any means, invest in a little infrastructure to get the best possible performance using `=` comparison internally. This will save a lot on I/O, CPU compared to any other approach. But also keep an eye on write performance degradation with the growing indexes. You might just come up with a trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

Trigram indexes are your only hope.

You used a GIN index and not a GiST index, right?

Make sure you dictate a minimum length for the search string, see that the result set is limited and the search is reasonably fast.

Answer (score 1):

If your pattern should match the start of the file name (without the path), then an alternative would be to index the last element of the path which then can be searched for using a right anchored pattern, e.g. `CT1_111%`:

```
create index idx_last_element on your_table 
    (((string_to_array(file_path,'/'))[cardinality(string_to_array(file_path,'/'))]) text_pattern_ops);
```

You then need to use that expression in your SQL query:

```
select *
from your_table
where (string_to_array(file_path,'/'))[cardinality(string_to_array(file_path,'/'))] like 'CT1_111%';
```

This would use the above index.

---

You can simplify your query by wrapping that expression in a function:

```
create or replace function extract_file_name(p_path text)
  returns text
as
$$  
  select elements[cardinality(elements)] 
  from (select string_to_array(p_path,'/') elements ) t;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

And use that function to create the index:

```
create index idx_file_name on your_table( (extract_file_name(file_path)) text_pattern_ops);
```

Then use that function in the query:

```
select *
from your_table
where extract_file_name(file_path) like 'CT1_111%';
```

On my Windows laptop using Postgres 11 with 2 million rows, this results in the following execution plan:

```
Index Scan using last_element on public.file_paths  (cost=0.43..2.69 rows=200 width=82) (actual time=0.193..0.437 rows=36 loops=1)
  Output: id, created_at, path
  Index Cond: ((extract_file_name(file_paths.path) ~>=~ 'CT1_111'::text) AND (extract_file_name(file_paths.path) ~<~ 'a504'::text))
  Filter: (extract_file_name(file_paths.path) ~~ 'CT1_111%'::text)
  Buffers: shared hit=36 read=3
  I/O Timings: read=0.066
Planning Time: 0.918 ms
Execution Time: 0.459 ms
```

Comment: Index scans with additional search filter will still become pretty slow as soon as more pages need to be fetched from disk as it still needs to search big parts of the index tree, although using a specific immutable function is better than to take care of the exact expression each time in the where clause and more readable. If combined with my approach for exact matches, it should result in readable queries as well as good performing ones even as the table and indexes grow because an exact index match will certainly reduce number of IOPS per query drastically.